# Input to fit a power-law to degree distribution of a network

Tags: networks, power-law, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn, igraph, quantiles

I would like to use `R` to test whether the degree distribution of a network behave like a power-law with scale-free property. Nonetheless, I've read diferent people doing this in many different ways, and one confusing point is the input one should use in the model.

I've for example read Barabasi recommending to fit the power-law to the 'complementary cumulative distribution' of degrees [(see Advanced Topic 3.B of chapter 4, figure 4.22](http://barabasi.com/networksciencebook). However, I've seen people fit a power-law to the degrees of the graph (obtained with `igraph::degree(g)`), and I've also seen others fitting a power-law to to degree distribution, obtained like this:  `igraph::degree_distribution(g, cumulative = T)`

As you can see in the reproducible example below, these two options give very different results. Which one is correct? In other words, how can I get the "complementary cumulative distribution of degrees" to from a graph so I can fit a power-law?

```
library(igraph)

# create a graph
  set.seed(202)
  g <- static.power.law.game(500, 1000, exponent.out= 2.2, exponent.in = 2.2, loops = FALSE, multiple = T)

# get input to fit power-law.

  # 1) degrees of the nodes
    d <- degree(g, v = V(g), mode ="all")
    d <- d[ d > 0] # remove nodes with no connection

  # OR ?

  # 2) cumulative degree distribution
    d <- degree_distribution(g, mode ="all", cumulative = T)

# Fit power law
  fit <- fit_power_law(d, impelementation = "R.mle")
```